# Android DialogFragment views not updating

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog

I am using a DialogFragment and onViewCreated is called, however the card views do not update their opacity.

My code should disable and grey out the card view that is not selected, however nothing changes.
I have tried placing the code in onCreateView instead but it does not work as well.

```
class AddBookDialogFragment: DialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return activity?.let {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
            // Get the layout inflater
            val inflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater

            // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
            // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_book, null))
                // Add action buttons
                .setPositiveButton("Create") { dialog, id ->
                    // create the book
                }
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { _, _ ->
                    dialog?.cancel()
                }
            builder.create()
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val addBookRadioGroup: RadioGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.add_book_radio_group)
        view.findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.isbn_radio_button).isEnabled = true

        addBookRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->
            // checkedId is the RadioButton selected

            val manualCardView: CardView = view.findViewById(R.id.manual_card_view)
            val isbnCardView: CardView = view.findViewById(R.id.isbn_card_view)

            var disabledCardView: CardView = manualCardView
            var enabledCardView: CardView = isbnCardView

            // Sets which card view will be enabled / disabled
            when (checkedId) {
                R.id.isbn_radio_button -> {
                    disabledCardView = manualCardView
                    enabledCardView = isbnCardView
                }

                R.id.manual_card_view -> {
                    disabledCardView = isbnCardView
                    enabledCardView = manualCardView
                }
            }

            disabledCardView.isEnabled = false
            // Sets opacity to 60%
            disabledCardView.alpha = 0.6F

            enabledCardView.isEnabled = true
            // Sets to opacity to 100%
            enabledCardView.alpha = 1F
        }
    }

    // On create view must be overridden here so that it does not return null, if it returns null onViewCreated won't run
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_book, container, false)
    }
}
```

My xml file is structured like this

```
<ConstraintLayout>

    <RadioGroup>
        
        <RadioButton>
        <CardView>
            some TextInputEditTexts to input fields
        </CardView>
        
        <RadioButton>
        <CardView>
            some TextInputEditTexts to input fields
        </CardView>
    </RadioGroup>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is how I display the DialogFragment

```
activity?.supportFragmentManager?.let { it ->
    AddBookDialogFragment().show(it, "Add Book")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try making a `view: View?` variable in your DialogFragment, and replace

```
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_book, null))
     .setPositiveButton("Create") { dialog, id ->
     }
     .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { _, _ ->
     dialog?.cancel()
     }
```

with

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_book, null)
builder.setView(view)
     .setPositiveButton("Create") { dialog, id ->
     }
     .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { _, _ ->
     dialog?.cancel()
     }
```

and remember to return the `view` variable in the `onCreateView` method instead of inflating another view.
Override the `onDestroyView` method as well to prevent memory leaks:

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
        view = null
        super.onDestroyView()
    }
```

Also, the `R.id.manual_card_view` in the switch statement should be `R.id.manual_radio_button`

As a note, enabling/disabling the card view will not effect the child views, so the text fields can still be interacted with.

Comment: Thanks! I figured this out before this answer was posted but it is entirely correct